# instanzaRfalse warning with reledmac/reledpar

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

Again a short question regarding an error that came up after the last update of `reledmac/reledpar`. My files were typesetted without problems before. Now it seems that something has changed. The ouput pdf is not affected directly but. still I was hoping to get rid of those warnings, but didn't find anything.

Here's the error log:

```
./Project.tex:125: Undefined control sequence.
\\Pages ...e \global \instanzaRfalse \if@ledgroup 
                                                  \else \global \l@dprinting...
l.125 \input{Title}
```

This `instanzaRfalse` comes up several times. Any ideas what I might have to check or change?

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

After trying different things, I must admit, that I can't reproduce the error within an MWE. Even the error log has changed with the last update to version 2.7 (new log-output is shown below).
I cannot figured out which parts of my main-file are responsable for that. The only thing I can tell for sure is, that ervery time a new `\input{file}` with a new pages-environment is called the following three warnings come up:

```
[35] [36] [37] (./Edition-Praefatio.tex
./Edition-Praefatio.tex:1: Undefined control sequence.
\pages ...ve@familiarfootnote@number \if@ledgroup 
                                                  \get@familiarfootnote@numb...
l.1 \begin{pages}

? 
./Edition-Praefatio.tex:1: Extra \fi.
\pages ...dgroup \get@familiarfootnote@number \fi 
                                                  \save@section@number \setl...
l.1 \begin{pages}

? 
Section 4 (./Pleiades-summa-res.4) (./Pleiades-summa-res.eledsec4) Section 2R 
(./Pleiades-summa-res.2R) (./Pleiades-summa-res.eledsec2R)
```

I don't no if that is helping anybody. On the other hand the output-pdf still seems not to be affected by this.

Comment: please provides MWE on reledmac issue pages. It seems it is a bug of reledmac, but I can't fix it without any MWE

Comment: Thanks. I will cut down my file in order to fit as MWE and post it to the issue pages later today.

Comment: hi, some news ?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error yesterday within a smaller environment. But it was obvious that the error comes up three times after inputting a new file in the main tex-file. Maybe there is a conincidence every time /Pages is called. But reducing the file with the exact preamble and only one input command didn't reproduce the error. I'm looking at it again, but I'm not very fast at the moment.

Comment: you can also send me an email with the full file. Just tell me in which version it was ok, and in which version it is not ok. I would do a bisect.